# Filtrar registros en Postgresql según varios parámetros

Tags: sql, postgresql

ante todo gracias por su tiempo. En la empresa donde trabajo poseo una DB en postgresql con las siguientes tablas:

- clientes (Id PK, razónsocial,documento...)
- vehiculos (Id PK, idtitular FK --> clientes(id),dominio ..)
- revisiones (id PK, idDominio FK --> vehiculos(id), ingreso timestamptz, egreso timestamptz, Vencimiento timestamptz)

Lo que necesito obtener es los registros que posean un vencimiento en el transcurso del mes, pero tengo por restricciones tener que separar por un lado los clientes que sean titulares de 2 o mas vehiculos y los que tienen solo 1 vehiculo. A su vez, solo requiero el ULTIMO registro de cada vehiculo. Esto dado que hay clientes que traen los vehiculos antes del vencimiento, por lo cual se genera otro registro con una fecha de vencimiento actualizada.

Para que se entienda,puede que tenga un registro donde hoy vence un vehiculo, pero resulta que el cliente vino ayer y se agrego un nuevo registro con vencimiento de acá a un año. Por lo cual ese vencimiento de hoy, ya no es valido y no me debería de salir en mi búsqueda del mes.

Lo mas cerca que estuve, es el poder generar un conteo de repeticiones con partition by como otra columna. Pero las primera repetición del cliente siempre da =1, por lo cual al utilizar where rn=1 siempre se me pianta algún vehiculo.

Mi query es el siguiente:

```
select * 
from 
(select *, 
   row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY PATENTE ORDER BY VENC desc) as rn 
   from (select v.dominio PATENTE,
         c.id TITID, 
         r.venc::timestamptz::date VENC, 
         c.id,
         r.id REVID 
         from tallermecanico.public.revision r 
         join vehiculo v 
         on r.iddominio = v.id 
         join clientes c 
         on c.id = v.idtitular 
         where r.venc::timestamptz::date between '2022-07-01' and '2022-07-31'
         ) as sqr1
) as sqr2 where rn=1
```

También he probado de obtener, utilizando la columna IDENTITY, los registros donde ese valor es máximo comparado con los otros. Esto me da los registros mas actualizados de cada vehiculo, pero no puedo filtrar si se repite el titular o no (SQL me tira 20 errores si lo intento)

```
select DISTINCT ON (v.dominio) r.id REVID 
from vehiculo v 
JOIN tallermecanico.public.revision r 
on v.id = r.iddominio  
and r.venc::timestamptz::date 
between'2022-07-01' and '2022-07-31' 
order by v.dominio,r.id desc
```

Actualmente uso ese ultimo en un for loop en Python, chequeando de una forma claramente infeciente si se repite algún titular. Estoy seguro que se debe poder hacer con query, Pero no se como.

Adjunto imágenes de las tablas para mayor contexto. (1. Clientes, 2. Revisiones, 3. Vehiculo)

Muchas gracias

[image: tabla cliente]

[image: tabla revision]

[image: tabla vehiculo]

Comment: ehem.... lo primero, pantallazos por favor, los menos posibles, ya que para reproducir el caso de prueba se hace muy complicado así. Y segundo, los datos parecen muy reales. Si son inventados, realmente son buenos. Si son reales de verdad, te sugiero que evites en lo posible usar nombres propios. Tus clientes podrían enfadarse si descubren que sus datos personales se usan arbitrariamente.

Comment: @RaulLuna Los datos son muy antiguos, solo modifique a mano los timestampz para que se entienda en el ejemplo del mes. Con respecto a los pantallazos que me pediste, no entendí a que te referís. Queres que te pase el output de esos querys??

Comment: Pues muy sencillo @Lucas, ponte en mi lugar: vamos a hacer una tabla de clientes, otra de vehiculos y otra de revisiones para verificar tu problema. Y les vamos a meter dados. Empecemos: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb ¿has visto que sólo hay creada una tabla y un registro??? ¿qué tal si metes el resto de datos para que yo pueda probar alguna consulta???? a eso me refiero, a que aquí nadie es un genio y viendo tus datos ya se imagina lo que hay que hacer: hay que probarlo, y para probarlo necesitas un entorno donde hacerlo

Comment: te falta la tabla de dominios, no? veo un id_dominio, veo el literal "dominio" en los vehiculos pero no veo cómo se emparejan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

valdría esto??? Adapta los campos que estimes oportuno ya que me parecía bastante confuso que "id_dominio" es en realidad "id_vehiculo" (supongo que se refiere a la matrícula del vehículo)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ca71f7/4

```
select *
from clientes cli
left join
(
select id_cliente, 
count(*) num_vehiculos
from vehiculos
group by id_cliente) vehiculos_por_cli
on cli.id_cliente = vehiculos_por_cli.id_cliente;

select rev.id_revision,
veh.id_vehiculo, 
veh.dominio, 
cli.razonsocial, 
cli.doc, 
vehiculos_por_cli.num_vehiculos, 
rev.ingreso, 
rev.egreso,
rev.vencimiento
from revisiones rev
inner join 
(
select id_vehiculo, 
max(ingreso) ultima_fecha_ingreso
from revisiones
group by id_vehiculo  
) ultima_fecha_rev
on rev.id_vehiculo = ultima_fecha_rev.id_vehiculo
and rev.ingreso = ultima_fecha_rev.ultima_fecha_ingreso
left join vehiculos veh
on veh.id_vehiculo = rev.id_vehiculo
left join clientes cli 
on veh.id_cliente = cli.id_cliente 
left join
(
select id_cliente, 
count(*) num_vehiculos
from vehiculos
group by id_cliente) vehiculos_por_cli
on cli.id_cliente = vehiculos_por_cli.id_cliente
where extract(month from vencimiento) = 7
and extract(year from vencimiento) =2022
order by rev.id_vehiculo;
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias , Lo retoque un poco pero me anduvo de maravilla!! Disculpa la tardanza en contestar, andaba a full con el laburo. Te agradesco por tu ayuda me salvaste.

Comment: @LucasDaligo77 marca la respuesta como correcta, anda....